# Getting the value of appended select list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just want to ask how to get the selected value from appended select list using jquery. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
var wrapper1 = $(".column1");

array1 = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3"];

var myRoot = window.location.origin + "/";
$.ajax({
    url: myRoot + 'Payslip/GetDataFromAppend',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //data: JSON.stringify({ id: $this }),
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {

        $(wrapper1).append(appendOption(data, array1[0]));

    }
});

var appendOption = function (data, txtData) {
    var appendfor = '<label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label> ' + txtData + '...</label></label><div class="col-sm-7">' +
        '<select class="form-control" asp-for="PayslipID" asp- items="ViewBag.PayslipID" data- val="true" data- val - required="The Payslip ID field is required." id= "PayslipID" >';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].value);
        appendfor += '<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].value + '</option>';
    }
    appendfor += '</select ></div >';
    return appendfor;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group column1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'form-control'  element is added to the page dynamically so you need to use event delegation, try this:

```
$(document).on('change', ".form-control", function(){
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

'column1' should also work in place of 'document' assuming that it is a static element.

Comment: Hi @Heidi, I have a another question. What if I have a multiple appended select list? How can I get all the values?